# Why can't I programmatically scroll to a given row in a YUI ScrollingDataTable?

Tags: scroll, yui-datatable

It appears the `ScrollingDataTable` `scrollTo` method is broken.

As an alternative, I've tried `scrollIntoView()` and jQuery's `scrollTop` on the correct dom elements without luck. I've also tried `YAHOO.util.Scroll` and it doesn't work either.

The datatable is in a div that has a vertical scrollbar.

jQuery version:

```
var scrollToThisRow = dataTable.getTrEl(recordToScrollTo);
var scrollPos = $(scrollToThisRow).position().top;
$('#tableBodyDiv').scrollTop(scrollPos);
```

Here's what I tried using YAHOO.util.Scroll:

```
var scrollToThisRow = dataTable.getTrEl(recordToScrollTo);
var scrollPos = $(scrollToThisRow).position().top;
var attributes = { 
  scroll: { to: [0, scrollPos] } 
};
var anim = new YAHOO.util.Scroll($('#tableBodyDiv'), attributes);
anim.animate();
```